# How to prove a vector field is hamiltonian?

Tags: classical-mechanics, tensor-calculus, hamiltonian-formalism

I've been studying Hamiltonian mechanics lately with kind of a more "differential geometry based" approach , but I'm stuck at a point where it is required to understand how you can prove a vector field is Hamiltonian.
For example if we are given the following simple system of equation, representing a one dimentional system on the phase space $T^{*}Q$
$$
 \dot{q}=f(q,p)\\
 \dot{p}=g(q,p)
$$
If the vector field they represent is Hamiltonian then there should be a function such that
$$
f=\frac{\partial H}{\partial q}\\
g=-\frac{\partial H}{\partial p}
$$
So by deriving we obtain
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial q}=\frac{\partial^2 H}{\partial q\partial p}=-\frac{\partial g}{\partial p}
$$
And we obtain that the condition is
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial q}+\frac{\partial g}{\partial p}=0
$$
Now on the phase space we have the symplectic 2-form $\omega$. We can define the 1-form $\mathit{i}_{X}\omega$ by setting $\mathit{i}_{X}\omega(Y)=\omega(X,Y)$ where X and Y are vector fields.
For an hamiltonian vector field $X_f$ we have $\mathit{i}_{X_{f}}\omega=-df$, so that we obviously have $d(\mathit{i}_{X}\omega)=-d(df)=0$.
Now we can represent a generic vector field $X=X^{\mu} \frac{{\partial }}{{\partial q^{\mu}}}+Y_{\mu}\frac{{\partial }}{{\partial p_{\mu}}}$
How can I prove that the condition that the vector field is Hamiltonian ($d(\mathit{i}_{X}\omega)=0$) writes as
$$
\frac{\partial X^{\mu}}{\partial q^{\lambda}}+\frac{\partial Y_{\lambda}}{\partial p_{\mu}}=0
$$
?
I've tried expressing $\omega=dp_{\mu}\wedge dq^{\mu}$ but then I dont know how to compute neither $\mathit{i}_{X}\omega$ nor $d(\mathit{i}_{X}\omega)$.
Thanks in advance for any help whatsoever.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue seems to be that you do not have sufficient practice with computations in charts. Note that calculating things like Lie-derivatives, exterior-derivatives, interior products etc are all very simple if you just learn the basic rules for them (and with some practice it becomes as simple as calculating that for $g(x) = e^{\sin(x^2)}$, we have $g'(x) = e^{\sin(x^2)}\cos(x^2) \cdot 2x$).

Note that things like interior derivative and exterior derivatives satisfy some form of the "product rule":

- $d(\alpha\wedge \beta) = d\alpha \wedge \beta + (-1)^{\deg \alpha} \alpha \wedge \beta$
- $X \,\lrcorner\, (\alpha\wedge \beta) = (X\, \lrcorner \, \alpha)\wedge \beta + (-1)^{\deg \alpha} \alpha \wedge (X\,\lrcorner\, \beta)$. i.e $\iota_X(\alpha\wedge \beta) = (\iota_X\alpha)\wedge \beta + (-1)^{\deg \alpha} \alpha \wedge (\iota_X\beta)$

Also, these are "local operators" in the sense that if you have a differential form $\alpha$ and an open set $U$ then $(d\alpha)|_U = d(\alpha|_U)$ (i.e restriction of exterior derivative is exterior derivative of restriction). Similarly for interior product. As a result of this, in order to calculate exterior derivatives/interior products, all you need to know is how to calculate it for $0$-forms and for $1$-forms. Then, in the general case of a $k$-form, you just expand it as $\alpha = \sum \alpha_{i_1\dots i_k}\, dx^{i_1}\wedge \dots \wedge dx^{i_k}$ and repeatedly apply the product rule (and the fact that these operations are $\Bbb{R}$-linear).

The only other thing you really need to know in order to calculate things is that for smooth functions $f$, we have $df = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i} dx^i$ and $X\, \lrcorner \, f = 0$, and for one-forms of the type $dg$, we have $d(dg) = 0$ and $X\, \lrcorner \,dg = dg(X) = \frac{\partial g}{\partial x^i} dx^i(X) =  \frac{\partial g}{\partial x^i} X^i$.

---

**Exterior Derivatives:**

So, for example, if we have a $k$-form $\alpha$, you can either prove from these axioms (or take as your definition) that if $\alpha = \sum_I \alpha_I dx^I \equiv \sum_I \alpha_{i_1\dots i_k} dx^{i_1}\wedge \dots \wedge dx^{i_k}$, (where $I$ is an injective tuple) then by repeatedly applying the product rule, and the rules for calculating $df$ and the rule that $d(df) = 0$, we find that
\begin{align}
d\alpha &= \sum_{I} d(\alpha_I)\wedge  dx^{i_1}\wedge \dots \wedge dx^{i_k}  \\
&= \sum_{I,j} \frac{\partial \alpha_I}{\partial x^j}\, dx^j \wedge dx^{i_1}\wedge \dots \wedge dx^{i_k}
\end{align}

---

**Interior Product:**

To calculate interior products, it's easily observed that $\iota_X\alpha$ is $C^{\infty}(M)$-linear in both the $X$ slot and also $\alpha$. This is why I've been using the $\lrcorner$ notation for interior product: it "almost behaves" like a "regular product" $\cdot$ in the sense that
\begin{align}
X\, \lrcorner \, \alpha &= \left(\sum_aX^a \frac{\partial}{\partial x^a}\right)\, \lrcorner \,
\left(\sum_I \alpha_I \, dx^I\right) = \sum_{a,I} X^a \alpha_I \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^a} \, \lrcorner \, dx^I\right)
\end{align}
So, you see, to calculate the interior product, all you need to know is how the interior product of the basic "coordinate vector fields" and "coordinate $1$-forms" works. Now, using repeated application of the product rule, and the fact that $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^a}\, \lrcorner \, dx^i = \frac{\partial x^i}{\partial x^a}=\delta^i_a$ (immediate consequence of the definitions), we see that
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x^a}\, \lrcorner \, (dx^{i_1}\wedge \dots dx^{i_k}) &= + \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^a} \, \lrcorner\,  dx^{i_1}\right) \cdot dx^{i_2}\wedge \dots \wedge dx^{i_k} \\
&\,\,- dx^{i_1}\wedge \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^a} \, \lrcorner\,  dx^{i_2}\right) dx^{i_3}\wedge \dots \wedge dx^{i_k} \\
&+ \cdots \\
& - \cdots \\
& + (-1)^k dx^{i_1}\wedge \dots \wedge dx^{i_{k-1}} \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^a} \, \lrcorner\,  dx^{i_k}\right) \\
\end{align}

In other words, you just alternate signs and replace subsequent $dx^i$'s by an appropriate $\frac{\partial x^i}{\partial x^a}=\delta^i_a$. If you want a single formula, then this is just
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x^a}\, \lrcorner \, (dx^{i_1}\wedge \dots dx^{i_k}) 
&= \sum_{\mu=1}^k (-1)^{\mu-1}\, \frac{\partial x^{i_{\mu}}}{\partial x^a} dx^{i_1}\wedge \dots \wedge \widehat{dx^{i_{\mu}}} \wedge \dots \wedge dx^{i_k}\\
&= \sum_{\mu=1}^k (-1)^{\mu-1}\, \delta^{i_{\mu}}_a \cdot dx^{i_1}\wedge \dots \wedge \widehat{dx^{i_{\mu}}} \wedge \dots \wedge dx^{i_k}
\end{align}
(Just try this out explicitly for the case $k=3,4,5$, and you'll definitely see the pattern)

---

Now, putting these rules together we can apply to your special case. For $X = X^{\mu}\frac{\partial}{\partial q^{\mu}} + Y_{\mu}\frac{\partial}{\partial p_{\mu}}$ and $\omega = dp_a\wedge dq^a$, we have:
\begin{align}
\iota_X\omega &\equiv X\, \lrcorner \, \omega \\
&= \left(X^{\mu}\frac{\partial}{\partial q^{\mu}} + Y_{\mu}\frac{\partial}{\partial p_{\mu}}\right) \, \lrcorner \, (dp_a\wedge dq^a) \\
&= X^{\mu}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial q^{\mu}} \, \lrcorner\, (dp_a\wedge dq^a) \right) 
+ Y_{\mu}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial p_{\mu}} \, \lrcorner\, (dp_a\wedge dq^a) \right) \\
&= X^{\mu}\left( \frac{\partial p_a}{\partial q^{\mu}} dq^a - \frac{\partial q^a}{\partial q^{\mu}} dp_a\right)
+
Y_{\mu}\left( \frac{\partial p_a}{\partial p_{\mu}} dq^a - \frac{\partial q^a}{\partial p_{\mu}} dp_a\right) \\
&= Y_{\mu} dq^{\mu} - X^{\mu} dp_{\mu}
\end{align}
(with some practice you'll be able to skip a few steps and keep track of what are the non-zero terms). So, now calculating the exterior derivative of this, we see that
\begin{align}
d(X \, \lrcorner\, \omega) &= d(Y_{\mu}) \wedge dq^{\mu} - d(X^{\mu}) \wedge dp_{\mu} \\
&= \left( \frac{\partial Y_{\mu}}{\partial q^{\lambda}}dq^{\lambda} + 
\frac{\partial Y_{\mu}}{\partial p_{\lambda}}dp_{\lambda} \right)\wedge dq^{\mu} 
- \left( \frac{\partial X^{\mu}}{\partial q^{\lambda}}dq^{\lambda} + 
\frac{\partial X^{\mu}}{\partial p_{\lambda}}dp_{\lambda} \right)\wedge dp_{\mu} \\
&= \left[\left(\frac{\partial X^{\mu}}{\partial q^{\lambda}} +
\frac{\partial Y_{\lambda}}{\partial p_{\mu}}\right) dp_{\mu}\wedge dq^{\lambda}\right] + 
\left[\frac{\partial Y_{\mu}}{\partial q^{\lambda}}\, dq^{\lambda}\wedge dq^{\mu}\right]
+ \left[\frac{\partial X^{\mu}}{\partial p_{\lambda}}\, dp_{\mu}\wedge dp_{\lambda}\right]
\end{align}
where in the last line, I did quite a bit of index juggling, along with the fact that wedge product is "anti-commutative"; i.e for $1$-forms $\alpha,\beta$, we have $\alpha\wedge \beta = - \beta \wedge \alpha$. Now, here, one must be careful because not all of the forms are linearly independent; we can rewrite this expression as:
\begin{align}
d(X \, \lrcorner\, \omega) &=
\sum_{\lambda,\mu} \left(\frac{\partial X^{\mu}}{\partial q^{\lambda}} +
\frac{\partial Y_{\lambda}}{\partial p_{\mu}}\right) dp_{\mu}\wedge dq^{\lambda}\\
&+
\sum_{\lambda < \mu} \left( \frac{\partial Y_{\mu}}{\partial q^{\lambda}} - \frac{\partial Y_{\lambda}}{\partial q^{\mu}}\right) dq^{\lambda}\wedge dq^{\mu} \\
&+ \sum_{\lambda < \mu} \left(\frac{\partial X^{\mu}}{\partial p_{\lambda}} - \frac{\partial X^{\lambda}}{\partial p_{\mu}} \right) dp_{\mu}\wedge dp_{\lambda}
\end{align}
Now, the forms are linearly independent, so $d(X\, \lrcorner \, \omega) = 0$ if and only if each of the coefficients vanishes: i.e if and only if:

\begin{align}
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{\partial X^{\mu}}{\partial q^{\lambda}} +
\dfrac{\partial Y_{\lambda}}{\partial p_{\mu}} &= 0 \quad \text{for all $\lambda,\mu \in\{1,\dots, n\}$}\\\\
\dfrac{\partial Y_{\mu}}{\partial q^{\lambda}} - 
\dfrac{\partial Y_{\lambda}}{\partial q^{\mu}} &= 0 \quad \text{for all $\lambda,\mu \in\{1,\dots, n\}$, such that $\lambda < \mu$} \\\\
\dfrac{\partial X^{\mu}}{\partial p_{\lambda}} - 
\dfrac{\partial X^{\lambda}}{\partial p_{\mu}} &= 0 \quad \text{for all $\lambda,\mu \in\{1,\dots, n\}$, such that $\lambda < \mu$}
\end{cases}
\end{align}
This condition is clearly equivalent to saying that for all $\lambda,\mu \in \{1,\dots, n\}$,
\begin{align}
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{\partial X^{\mu}}{\partial q^{\lambda}} +
\dfrac{\partial Y_{\lambda}}{\partial p_{\mu}} = 0\\\\
\dfrac{\partial Y_{\mu}}{\partial q^{\lambda}} =
\dfrac{\partial Y_{\lambda}}{\partial q^{\mu}} \\\\
\dfrac{\partial X^{\mu}}{\partial p_{\lambda}} = 
\dfrac{\partial X^{\lambda}}{\partial p_{\mu}} \tag{$\ddot{\smile}$}
\end{cases}
\end{align}

So, the condition for a vector field $X$ on a symplectic manifold to be locally-Hamiltonian (i.e $\mathcal{L}_X\omega = d(X \,\lrcorner\, \omega) = 0$), expressed in terms of a Darboux Coordinate system is the set PDEs $(\ddot{\smile})$.

Answer (score 2):

Well, let me use the following notation for vectors in Darboux coordinates
$$X=X^\mu_{(q)}\frac{\partial}{\partial q^\mu}+X_\mu^{(p)}\frac{\partial}{\partial p_\mu}.$$
We then have
$$\omega(X,Y)=X_\mu^{(p)}Y^\mu_{(q)}-X^\mu_{(q)}Y_\mu^{(p)}.$$
From this we conclude that
$$\iota_X\omega=\omega(X,\cdot)=X_\mu^{(p)}\text{d}q^\mu-X^\mu_{(q)}\text{d}p_\mu.$$
Now, the Hamiltonian condition reads
$$0=\text{d}(\iota_X\omega)=\left(\frac{\partial X_\mu^{(p)}}{\partial p^\nu}+\frac{\partial X^\mu_{(p)}}{\partial q^\nu}\right)\text{d}p_\nu\wedge\text{d}q^\mu,$$
which is the result you were looking for.

Comment: I don't think your calculation of the exterior derivative is right, because you're missing terms like $dq^{\nu}\wedge dq^{\mu}$ and $dp_{\nu}\wedge dp_{\mu}$. (see my answer below)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, let us agree on terminology: In a [symplectic manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_manifold) $(M,\omega)$ a [Hamiltonian vector field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_vector_field) (HVF) $X_f$ is always a [symplectic vector field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_vector_field) (SVF) ${\cal L}_X\omega=0$, which in local coordinates reads
$$ 0~=~({\cal L}_X\omega)_{IJ}~=~X[\omega_{IJ}] +(\partial_I X^K)\omega_{KJ}+ \omega_{IK}(\partial_J X^K), \qquad I,J~\in~\{1,\ldots,2n\}. $$
Conversely, a SVF is a HVF locally in [contractable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contractible_space) neighborhoods, but not necessarily globally.

Comment: Does this answer the question? It looks an awful lot like a comment to me. Granted I am new to the mathematics here, but I don't see what's being suggested as the path forward.  This is how the solution would be critiqued on math.SE anyhow.  Thanks for humoring me while I learn more about the physics.se culture and its differences.

Comment: I updated the answer.

Comment: Is the implicit solution "check that condition"?  As written it just looks like "let's agree on terms. An HVF is an SVF, but not always conversely." The only apparent use of this would be to disprove it's an HVF by showing it's not an SVF...